# Plex media server on Raspberry pi zero w not working

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, plex

I'm trying to install Plex media server on my raspberrypi zero w and i keep getting this error:

```
plexmediaserver.service - Plex Media Server for Linux
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/plexmediaserver.service; enabled; 
vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-09-06 18:22:09 UTC; 12s ago
Process: 1043 ExecStart=/bin/sh -c LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/plexmediaserver "/usr/lib/plexmediaserv
Process: 1039 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c /usr/bin/test -d "${PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_APPLICATION_SUPPORT_DIR
Main PID: 1043 (code=exited, status=132)

Sep 06 18:22:04 raspberrypi systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 06 18:22:04 raspberrypi systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 06 18:22:09 raspberrypi systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduli
Sep 06 18:22:09 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped Plex Media Server for Linux.
Sep 06 18:22:09 raspberrypi systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Sep 06 18:22:09 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start Plex Media Server for Linux.
Sep 06 18:22:09 raspberrypi systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 06 18:22:09 raspberrypi systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

If anyone can help I'd really appreciate it, Thanks!
(btw I'm quite a noob when it comes to raspberry pi's)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know it is not supported anymore due to lots of API changes of Plex resulting in the discontinued support of ARM v61 (Pi Zero W has ARM v61) and only "supports" ARM v7 and v8 (v64)

See also: https://forums.plex.tv/t/pi-zero-w-problems/191899/7